# Certain website returning Null with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

So I'm trying to scrape a website and I'm using HTML Agility Pack to try and do this. I have tried my code on the html-agility-pack and google websites and it seem to work fine with this simple search.

My problem is the code is returning an error ("System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'") on this line of code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + node.Name + "\n" + node.OuterHtml);
```

I understand this is happening because the var node is returning Null but why is this happening on this website and not on the others?

```
        //var html = @"http://html-agility-pack.net/";
        var html = @"https://www./";
        //var html = @"https://www.google.com/";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

        if (web.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CONNECTION OK");
            var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title");

            Console.WriteLine("Node Name: " + node.Name + "\n" + node.OuterHtml);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Connection to website");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine for me

Comment: @uda It worked the first time but then its returns Null after. I put a loop in and tried a few pages from that site but its not working at all. I think the site is somehow blocking the scraper, is there any way to get around it?

Comment: can you please show the entire loop code also

Comment: @uda sorry for the late reply, I found out the website was redirecting me to a robot page as it recognised I was scraping. I manually copy and pasted the data I need as I didnt know a way around it.